# Imagepng lets script run twice

Tags: php

Somehow imagepng makes my script run twice.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

if(isset($_GET['token'])) {
    if($core->captchaTokenExists($_GET['token'])){
        $token = $_GET['token'];
        $captchaCode = $core->newCaptcha($token);

        //Image generation
        $imageWidth = 184;
        $imageHeight = 70;
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);

        imagettftext($image, 13, 0, 30, 40, imagecolorallocate($image, 50, 50, 50), 'core/font/captcha.ttf', $captchaCode);

        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    }
}
```

The text appearing on the image is randomly generated with newCaptcha($token). As an example, it shows "IGWVID". But in the database it shows "JNNYSN".

I used the following code to debug the php code and see what happens;

```
file_put_contents('debug.txt', file_get_contents('debug.txt') . time() . PHP_EOL);
```

I receive the following output:

```
1400870202
1400870202
```

newCaptcha($token):

```
public function newCaptcha($token) {
    try {
        global $Db;
        $answer = $this->generateString(6);

        $Db->query("UPDATE `captcha` SET `answer` = :answer WHERE `token` = :token");
        $Db->bind(":answer", $answer);
        $Db->bind(":token", $token);
        $Db->execute();

        return $answer;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->addToResponse('false', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

generateString($length):

```
public function generateString($length) {
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";  
    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        @$str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Why is it doing this?

**Edit:** I just found out that the header is causing the problem. I removed the header and made the captchaCode echo out before the imagepng code, its the same one as in the database.

**Edit 2:** This does only happen in firefox, but doesn't happen in chrome.

Comment: there is **ZERO** point in `file_put_contents(... file_get_contents())`. you risk blowing up the PHP memory limit if your log file gets "big",b ecause you're slurping the ENTIRE file into memory before spitting it right back out again. All you need is `file_put_contents($text, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: And if the code runs twice, then it's being called twice. Are you displaying your captcha multiple times in the same page? Each separate image would regenerate the captcha and store a different random token, and all of the image hits would likely come into the server at about the same time anyways.

Comment: I am generating the captcha one time. The script I posted above is the whole page that loads. It works fine if I just echo out the new generated captcha WITHOUT the image being generated. It runs one time too then.

Comment: @MarcB , That line is there for debugging purposes. I keep the log clean.